# Как определить в элементах одного класса наличие одного CSS свойства

Tags: javascript, jquery

Даны несколько `div` одного класса. У всех есть `css` свойство `top`. Нужно определить, есть ли хоть в одном `div`-е свойство `top: 120px`. Желательно на `jquery`.

Comment: Это какой-то специальный таск для того что бы скрутить всем карму?)))) Вроде у всех рабочие варианты, но все ушли в минус ... xDDDD

Comment: Я бы отдал всем голос, но репутация в stackoverflow не позволяет)

Comment: @MedvedevDev, все ответы плохи, потому что представляют собой просто кусок кода, непонято что и как делающий, ну и еще вариант, что минусы за оффтопичный вопрос, в котором просто задача описана и не видно желания разобраться :-)

Comment: @Grundy, сложно поспорить, но за что купили, за то и продали ... )))

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```js
var exists = false; // флаг для определения наличия элемента с top:120px;
$('.block').each(function() {
  if ($(this).css('top') == '120px') { // если подходит условияю
    exists = true; // переключаем флаг
    console.log($(this).text());
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  background: #e1e1e1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">1</div>
<div class="block">2</div>
<div class="block">3</div>
<div class="block" style="top:120px;">4</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Как я понял по вопросу что то такое :

```
var arr = $("div");
for (var i=0;i < arr.length;i++) {
    if (arr.eq(i).css("top") == "120px") {
    // магия
    }
}
```

[JSFIDD Клик](https://jsfiddle.net/fx9gevkn/)

Answer (score -3):

```js
let height120 = false;

$('div').each(function() {
  if($(this).css('top') === '120px') {
    height120 = true;
    
    return false;
  }
});

console.log(height120);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="top: 10px;"></div>
<div style="top: 10px;"></div>
<div style="top: 10px;"></div>
<div style="top: 10px;"></div>
<div style="top: 10px;"></div>
<div style="top: 10px;"></div>
<div style="top: 10px;"></div>
<div style="top: 120px;"></div>
<div style="top: 10px;"></div>
<div style="top: 10px;"></div>
<div style="top: 10px;"></div>
<div style="top: 10px;"></div>
```